# Using ng-model on prototype properties, cannot edit input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, prototype, prototype-programming

Plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/l9ZzBilMaf3eJgXDNcaK

I have a funny feeling this is related to the prototypical model and I should be doing some clever binding but I can't figure it out.

I'm trying to improve existing code and I'm experimenting with prototypical constructors with angularjs factories. As you can see it all seems to work great except that I cannot edit an input field which has been bound to a property of one of my created objects.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:) Every key press, ng-model of input changes – this causes $digest to run, so each time your bindings are being triggered, including this one: `{{details1.setTestObject({hello: "World"})}}`.
It sets 'hello' back to 'World' and triggers another one $digest.

I made console log on setTestObject method - it runs three times each time I press key.

Check [this one](http://plnkr.co/edit/t6666G4j9tB8HefTMAHG?p=preview). All i've done is changed `{{details1.setTestObject({hello: "World"})}}` to `<span ng-init="details1.setTestObject({hello: 'World'})"></span>`, so it doesn't evaluate every $digest cycle and not changes your variable back.

Comment: Wow, sometimes you just get so lost in the advanced stuff that you completely miss the obvious! Thank you so much you've saved me about half a head of hair :)